# Make an array from multiple strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a filename variable which returns a string of multiple file names.

I want to join all file names to 1 array.

I tried many methods but they didn't work

here is my code:

`console.log(filename);`

returns:

```
4ca9da0b-177b-4e8b-ab10-a9633720c1c8getg3434yy.jpg
c721af11-5e6a-43ce-8acc-c9ab86c94c6fhe45yu45uy54y45uj4ju.jpg
3f8e602c-aa64-4c8f-ac5e-ad824bfbfc34h34yh3hyjk5 456j.png
fb05e659-be7a-4f81-8f16-5fb270121b3brjk5ryjkj64iju6i.jpg
```

i want to join them into an array like this:

```
[a950e85b-7cec-487d-9186-38d131d83772g34ygh3435hyu4uu.jpg,
4ca9da0b-177b-4e8b-ab10-a9633720c1c8getg3434yy.jpg,
c721af11-5e6a-43ce-8acc-c9ab86c94c6fhe45yu45uy54y45uj4ju.jpg,
3f8e602c-aa64-4c8f-ac5e-ad824bfbfc34h34yh3hyjk5 456j.png,
fb05e659-be7a-4f81-8f16-5fb270121b3brjk5ryjkj64iju6i.jpg]
```

i tried:

```
let array = [];
for (let index = 0; index <= filename.length; index++) {
const element = filename[index];
array.push(element);
}
console.log(array);
```

but it returns for  each string like this:

```
[
  'c56f6f49-197c-46a4-8f33-eb92c7486410g34ygh3435hyu4uu.jpg','c','5','6','f','6','f','4','9','-','1','9','7','c','-','4','6','a','4','-','8','f','3','3','-','e','b','9','2','c','7','4','8','6','4','1','0','g','3','4','y','g','h','3','4','3','5','h','y','u','4','u','u','.','j','p','g',
  undefined,
]
[
  'c56f6f49-197c-46a4-8f33-eb92c7486410g34ygh3435hyu4uu.jpg','c','5','6','f','6','f','4','9','-','1','9','7','c','-','4','6','a','4','-','8','f','3','3','-','e','b','9','2','c','7','4','8','6','4','1','0','g','3','4','y','g','h','3','4','3','5','h','y','u','4','u','u','.','j','p','g',
  undefined
]
[
  '14ac4973-cdf8-4657-9075-d81c288a7dc1h34yh3hyjk5 456j.png','1','4','a','c','4','9','7','3','-','c','d','f','8','-','4','6','5','7','-','9','0','7','5','-','d','8','1','c','2','8','8','a','7','d','c','1','h','3','4','y','h','3','h','y','j','k','5',' ','4','5','6','j','.','p','n','g',
  undefined
]
[
  '6a9214e7-6840-445f-98c8-c40bb660727drjk5ryjkj64iju6i.jpg','6','a','9','2','1','4','e','7','-','6','8','4','0','-','4','4','5','f','-','9','8','c','8','-','c','4','0','b','b','6','6','0','7','2','7','d','r','j','k','5','r','y','j','k','j','6','4','i','j','u','6','i','.','j','p','g',
  undefined
]
[
  '1534bb5c-6ab1-4d26-a9d0-6ec73b377272getg3434yy.jpg','1','5','3','4','b','b','5','c','-','6','a','b','1','-','4','d','2','6','-','a','9','d','0','-','6','e','c','7','3','b','3','7','7','2','7','2','g','e','t','g','3','4','3','4','y','y','.','j','p','g',
  undefined
]
[
  'c090778c-feab-4c4d-925a-462d289cbf4ehe45yu45uy54y45uj4ju.jpg','c','0','9','0','7','7','8','c','-','f','e','a','b','-','4','c','4','d','-','9','2','5','a','-','4','6','2','d','2','8','9','c','b','f','4','e','h','e','4','5','y','u','4','5','u','y','5','4','y','4','5','u','j','4','j','u','.','j','p','g',
  undefined
]
```

thanks for answering

Edit: Full code

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { File } from "formidable";
import Formidable from "formidable-serverless";
import fs from "fs";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
export default function uploadFormFiles(req: Request, res: Response) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm({
      multiples: true,
      keepExtensions: true,
    });

    form
      .on("file", (name: string, file: File) => {
        const filename = uuidv4() + file.name;
        let array = [];
        for (let index = 0; index <= filename.length; index++) {
          const element = filename[index];
          array.push(element);
        }
        console.log(array);

        const data = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
        fs.writeFileSync(`public/upload/${filename}`, data);
        fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
      })
      .on("aborted", () => {
        reject(res.status(500).send("Aborted"));
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        resolve(res.status(200).send("done"));
      });

    await form.parse(req);
  });
}
```

EDIT 2: SOLUTION:
filename is generated really weirdly... its generated from TypeScript somehow filename is generated from multiple arrays inside an object...so i got filenames using plain JS :

```
 const fields = new Formidable.IncomingForm({
      multiples: true,
      keepExtensions: false,
    });

    fields.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    let filename = files.file.map((a) => uuidv4() + a.name);
    }
```

Comment: Show us what `filee` is. It seems like you are iterating over a string upon the second iteration, which causes the garbled output you are seeing.

Comment: How do you get all the filenames?

Comment: @Terry i'm sorry filee is supposed to be filename

Comment: i copied it from my project code so i forgot to change it, updated code with full details

Comment: @Reyno i get it from a form which is has an input field of files 
user can select multiple files and upload them to the server everything works file but i cant join the file names to an array

Comment: What logic is generating those filenames? You need to access it and push that into the array: by the time you have access to individual file names (which your code is doing), you are creating **a new array for each filename**. Show us the code that generates the list of filenames.

Comment: @Terry i added the full code

Comment: It might help to see the output from:
console.log(JSON.stringify(filename));

Comment: @Andrew it didnt work

Comment: You're using an async method to set the filenames: you will need to modify your `uploadFormFiles` function so that it resolves the promise with the filename. And then from the part in your code where you call `uploadFormFiles`, you will need to collate the filenames from the resolved promises, wait for all promises to be resolved: and that's when you have access to the full array of filenames.

Comment: @Terry file name is just a variable set to an uuid with file.name, file.name is resolved from the promise

Comment: @AlandSleman As far as I can tell you are not resolving with the filename. You are resolving the promise with `res.status(200).send("done")`. In that way, you will never have access to the filename outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

const array = filename.split('\n');

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Since Op has not shown a proper example, we cannot know if splitting on string would be the answer, if it is, then it is not worth an answer

Comment: @mplungjan i think this is indeed an answer as it answers the given question. Other separators might be \r or \0 but with the OP question one cannot know for sure

Comment: it didnt works it returns:

[ 'b0662a2a-6d5a-45f9-b020-abfc3d292afag34ygh3435hyu4uu.jpg' ]
[ 'cc0cc4c3-7e95-4780-ad14-712c77d6f105h34yh3hyjk5 456j.png' ]
[ '71c1f303-1ee3-4dda-be15-dadedbfd8d25getg3434yy.jpg' ]
[ '82b65749-b7cd-4547-a5e4-e9eaa0d1908crjk5ryjkj64iju6i.jpg' ]
[ '98a00c69-1b31-402e-b132-15698f9dff40he45yu45uy54y45uj4ju.jpg' ]

Comment: @mplungjan I think you're probably right. There wasn't enough information to provide an accurate answer. To be honest I didn't realize that there was much of a difference between an answer and a comment but I get it now. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @AlandSleman that looks like your requested array? Why does that not do what you want?

Comment: @mplungjan no its not an array its multiple strings,look at this:

        console.log(typeof filename);
returns
string
string
string
string
string

Answer (score 0):

From what i guess you'll receive one 'file' event for each selected line in the form. Then you can store each filename and finally on the 'end' event you know the full list of files:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { File } from "formidable";
import Formidable from "formidable-serverless";
import fs from "fs";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
export default function uploadFormFiles(req: Request, res: Response) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new Formidable.IncomingForm({
      multiples: true,
      keepExtensions: true,
    });
    const arr = [];
    form
      .on("file", (name: string, file: File) => {
        const filename = uuidv4() + file.name;
        arr.push(filename);

        const data = fs.readFileSync(file.path);
        fs.writeFileSync(`public/upload/${filename}`, data);
        fs.unlinkSync(file.path);
      })
      .on("aborted", () => {
        reject(res.status(500).send("Aborted"));
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log(arr);
        resolve(res.status(200).send("done"));
      });

    await form.parse(req);
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i already found the solution...filename is generated really weirdly... its generated from TypeScript somehow filename is generated from multiple arrays inside an object...i added the solution in the bottom my my question